# PHP: Selecting random values from associative array

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

I have an associative array which I'm looping though to display all the information

Here's my simplified code.

```
    <?php

    $preview_content = array();
    $preview_content[0] = array(
    "preview_title" => "1. Placeholder Text h2",
    "preview_text" => "1.Lorem ipsum Deserunt eu nulla et sunt."
    );


    $preview_content[1] = array(
    "preview_title" => "2. Placeholder Text h2",
    "preview_text" => "2 .Lorem ipsum Deserunt eu nulla et sunt pariatur."
    );

    $preview_content[2] = array(
    "preview_title" => "3. Placeholder Text h2",
    "preview_text" => "3 .Lorem ipsum Deserunt eu nulla et sunt pariatur ex Duis dolore."
    );

    $preview_content[3] = array(
    "preview_title" => "4. Placeholder Text h2",
    "preview_text" => "4 .Lorem ipsum Deserunt eu nulla et sunt pariatur ex  Duis dolore."
    );

    $preview_content[4] = array(
    "preview_title" => "5. Placeholder Text h2",
    "preview_text" => "5 .Lorem ipsum Deserunt eu nulla et sunt pariatur ex   Duis dolore deserunt reprehenderit ."
    );

    $preview_content[5] = array(
    "preview_title" => "6. Placeholder Text h2",
    "preview_text" => "6 .Lorem ipsum Deserunt eu nulla et sunt pariatur ex   Duis."
    );

    // $rand = array_rand($preview_content);

     ?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="preview-wrap">
    <ul>


    <?php  foreach($preview_content as $preview) {?>
        <li>
        <h2 class="sm-prev-title"><?php echo $preview["preview_title"]; ?></h2>
          <div class="preview">
            <p><?php echo $preview["preview_text"]; ?></p>
          </div>
        </li>
    <?php } ?>

    </ul>
    </div>


</body>
</html>
```

What i need to do is echo this information in a random order each time and idealy also have the option to choose how many results will be displayed, so instead of all 6 maybe only 3 of them, and also for there to be no repeated results.

If I'm asking for to much here, that's fine just having them display in a random order would be a great start for me.

I've been trying to do this for hours now, but haven't really got anywhere yet so I'm hoping somebody out there can help me.

Comment: If you just want to randomly sort the array look at [shuffle](http://php.net/shuffle). Then you can just loop over the array and it will loop in that random order. replace the `array_rand` comment in your code with just `shuffle($preview_content);`. The loop below will show a different order every time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Get Unique Array First -** To get the unique array before the shuffle, run array_unique() on the array.

**Shuffle Array Second -** I agree with Johnathan Kuhn's comment, definitely use shuffle() to randomize.

**Limit Output Third -** To limit your output, add the $key to your foreach and break when the key is too high:

```
<?php  foreach($preview_content as $key => $preview) {?>
    <?php if($key > 3){ break; } ?>
    <li>
        <h2 class="sm-prev-title"><?php echo $preview["preview_title"]; ?></h2>
        <div class="preview">
            <p><?php echo $preview["preview_text"]; ?></p>
        </div>
    </li>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you can try is `array_rand()` with the second parameter (which defines the number of elements to choose).

```
$count = 3;
$rand_keys = array_rand($preview_content, 3);
foreach ($rand_keys as $key) {
    echo $preview_content[$key]["preview_title"];
}
```

Additionally, just as an idea: you will presumably get the data from a database. MySQL has ways to give back a random order as well. This way you have some randomness right from the beginning.

```
SELECT value
FROM database.table
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 5
```